# Why const member syntax behaves like static members of a class

Tags: c#, static, constants

Today I was trying to declare a static variable `EmployeeMaxAge` as shown in the code below:

```
namespace NewApplication
{
    public class CommonConstants
    {
        public const int EmployeeMaxHeightInCm = 160;
        public static int EmployeeMaxAge = 50; //new static member
    }
}
```

As I tried using it in my main method as `CommonConstants.EmployeeMaxAge` I could suddenly see that intellisense is also showing `EmployeeMaxHeightInCm` (which doesn't have a static modifier) in the intellisense drop down as well. So I wrote `CommonConstants.EmployeeMaxHeightInCm` in the code instead and saw that it is compiling and running successfully. I always knew that `ClassName.MemberName` syntax was only applicable for static members of a class but the same syntax is working for const members also. Can someone help me understand this behavior with respect to C# language?

Comment: This syntax is also valid for `const` members. Why do you think otherwise? Do you have a source that says that only static members are available on the class type identifier?

Comment: Also note that the member declaration where you have placed `//new constant` is in fact not a constant, but a static mutable field with an initializer. Please ensure we're talking about the same things here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen. True. I modified my question. I wasn't adding a const but a public static member.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have always been accessing only static members through `ClassName.MemberName` syntax. I'm not sure if there are other class constructs also which can use this syntax.

Comment: You can access static members (which includes const members), nested types, at least. Off the top of my head I am not sure there are others that are legal for `Type.Name` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: Because that is how the C# standard defines constant fields.

From section ***10.4 Constants***:

> Even though constants are considered static members, a constant-declaration neither requires nor allows a static modifier.
>
> ...
>
> The value of a constant is obtained in an expression using a simple-name (§7.6.2) or a member-access (§7.6.4).